# Getting fastapi to use the access token in the header

Tags: jwt, fastapi

Incredibly dumb question probably.

I have a fairly large fastapi app that I now want to add user accounts to. I’ve settled on [fastapi-login](https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login) as it looks simple enough. I’ve implemented what in the readme page.

My problem: when visiting the route that generates a token, I get an access token (as expected). However, on a next visit to a protected route, the token isn’t used in the Authorization Header, hence I get a Not Authorized error.

My question: how can I get my browser sessions to send the authorization header with token?

Comment: Depending on how you're calling the API - if you're calling it from a frontend application (Vue/React/Svelte/Mobile app/etc.) Usually you then store it in `localStorage` in the application, then include it in every request you make afterwards. This is something that's up to your own application to handle and isn't done automagically for you.

Comment: That’s the crux of the question: I’m using fastapi as web app. Is there an example somewhere of how to include this on the front end for python?

Comment: If you're rendering plain HTML and not using it as an API only, read the "Usage with cookies" section for fastapi-login: https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login#usage-with-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using plain HTML response then you will need to use cookie to login. Check the below code to implement the actual cookie login with the package `fastapi-login`

### using cookies

> main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi_login import LoginManager
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from fastapi_login.exceptions import InvalidCredentialsException

SECRET = 'your-secret-key'
manager = LoginManager(SECRET, token_url='/auth/token')

@manager.user_loader()
def load_user(email: str):  # could also be an asynchronous function
    # get actual username and password from db for the given email
    user = {"username": "abcd@email.com", "password": "secret"}
    return user

app = FastAPI()

# add cookie login route
@app.get('/auth')
def auth(response: Response, data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    email = data.username
    password = data.password

    user = load_user(email)  # we are using the same function to retrieve the user
    if not user:
        raise InvalidCredentialsException  # you can also use your own HTTPException
    elif password != user['password']:
        raise InvalidCredentialsException
    # get token and set cookie
    token = manager.create_access_token(
        data=dict(sub=user.email)
    )
    manager.set_cookie(response, token)
    return response

# now add protected route
@app.get('/protected')
def protected_route(user=Depends(manager)):
    ...
```

Reference: https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login#usage-with-cookies

Comment: I've looked at this example, but this doesn't seem to make sense? How can a login route /auth depend on a logged-in user through Depends(manager)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the token somewhere on client side and then send it in the header of every request. How you put it in the header depends on the library you are using to perform HTTP requests. For exemple, if you use python `requests` library, [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) are the docs.

However, this can still create some security vulnerabilities if your token is stolen (in a CSRF attack, for example). What I do is to let the token have a very short lifetime (let's say, some seconds) and demand a new token on a background thread whenever the old token is close to expire. But of course you need to take care with concurrent access to the token (with mutexes, for example).

Comment: I’m using fastapi as a web app. Reading your comment makes my head hurt, as I’m consuming the api (the site) via the browser…I’m  missing something obvious here.

Comment: I see. I think you are confusing the URL that is put in the browser and the API endpoint that is called to get the page. Once your web server serves you the front-end file associated to an URL (can be a javascript file, for example), you should call the API endpoint inside this front-end file to get the html to render. The URL knows nothing about the HTTP verbosity. This is left to the API endpoint call that is inside your front-end file.